# If $ab+ac+bc+abc=4$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}}{b+c}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc+abc=4$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}}{b+c}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{b^2}}{a+c}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{c^2}}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

I think it's interesting because $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$ it's just Nesbitt,

while $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{b+c}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{a+c}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}{2}$ is wrong already ($a=b=2$ and $c=0$).

An example of my trying.

By Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2}}{b+c}\right)^3\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c)^3\geq(a+b+c)^4.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$8(a+b+c)^4\geq27\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c)^3,$$
which seems true, but I have no a proof.

We can use the following substitution $a=\frac{2x}{y+z}$, $b=\frac{2y}{x+z}$, $c=\frac{2z}{x+y}$, but I think it's nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: Hello Sonnhard! It's one of my old unsolved problems.